# Install multiple deb files while respecting their dependencies

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, debian-installer

To support **offline installation** of multiple `.deb` files, I'm using:

```
sudo dpkg -i dependencies/*.deb
```

I've noticed some packages **fail using this method** because of the order they installed

**For example,**  this is what happens when I install `mariadb-server-5.5` and its dependencies:

[image: these are the files]

[image: this is the error]

### How can I Install `*.deb` files while respecting their dependencies?

- I'm trying to avoid setting up a local repo, since it's harder to maintain.
- As a workaround, I run command `dpkg -i *.deb` twice.

Comment: Have you tried [GDebi](/q/23657/175814)? It's a tad more intelligent than plain `dpkg` concerning dependency management. You can simulate the resulting actions with the `--apt-line` flag.

Comment: This is an old question but hopefully you can get back to the community on how you did this? I'd be interested in whether you tried 1) Just running the installation twice (second pass should be OK?) or 2) Any other alternative, like apt-get install -f

Comment: @pzkpfw  currently just running the installation twice. Planning to write a python script to sort the dependencies in topological order. Will update as soon as I'll deploy it

Comment: If it ain't broke don't fix it I guess :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Topological sort (via script)

The command <strike>`dpkg -i packages/*.deb`</strike> **is problematic** - does not properly respect the order packages should be installed (even if you supply all required packages).

#### Custom script to rule them all

> Under the assumption your debian distro **has python installed** (mine is ubuntu 14.04 LTS and comes with `python27`)

Aside the offline .deb `packages` directory, provide a script that;

- Extract metadata and [Topological sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) all candidate packages
- Uses `dpkg -i` to install the sorted packages in proper order they should be installed

---

**For example,** execute this command to install all pre-collected offline packages

```
sudo python install.py
```

> - Your directory structure should look like this
>
>   [image]

---

**install.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import re
import subprocess
import logging

import sys

rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"))
rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class TopologicalSort(object):
    def __init__(self, dependency_map):
        self._dependency_map = dependency_map
        self._already_processed = set()

    def _get_dependencies(self, item, root=None):

        if not root:
            root = item

        elif root == item:
            logging.warn("circular dependency detected in '{}'".format(item))
            raise StopIteration()

        dependencies = self._dependency_map.get(item, [])
        for dependency in dependencies:

            if dependency in self._already_processed:
                continue

            self._already_processed.add(dependency)

            for sub_dependency in self._get_dependencies(dependency, root=root):
                yield sub_dependency

            yield dependency

    def sort(self):
        # Reduction, connect all nodes to a dummy node and re-calculate
        special_package_id = 'topological-sort-special-node'
        self._dependency_map[special_package_id] = self._dependency_map.keys()
        sorted_dependencies = self._get_dependencies(special_package_id)
        sorted_dependencies = list(sorted_dependencies)
        del self._dependency_map[special_package_id]

        # Remove "noise" dependencies (only referenced, not declared)
        sorted_dependencies = filter(lambda x: x in self._dependency_map, sorted_dependencies)
        return sorted_dependencies


class DebianPackage(object):
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        metadata = subprocess.check_output('dpkg -I {}'.format(file_path), shell=True)
        metadata = metadata.replace('\n ', '\n')
        self._metadata = metadata
        self.id = self._get('Package')
        self.dependencies = list(self._get_dependencies())
        self.file_path = file_path

    def _get_dependencies(self):
        dependencies = self._get('Depends') + ',' + self._get('Pre-Depends')
        dependencies = re.split(r',|\|', dependencies)
        dependencies = map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\(.*\)|:any', '', x).strip(), dependencies)
        dependencies = filter(lambda x: x, dependencies)
        dependencies = set(dependencies)
        for dependency in dependencies:
            yield dependency

    def _get(self, key):
        search = re.search(r'\n{key}:(.*)\n[A-Z]'.format(key=key), self._metadata)
        return search.group(1).strip() if search else ''


def sort_debian_packages(directory_path):
    file_names = os.listdir(directory_path)
    debian_packages = {}
    dependency_map = {}
    for file_name in file_names:

        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, file_name)

        if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
            continue

        debian_package = DebianPackage(file_path)
        debian_packages[debian_package.id] = debian_package
        dependency_map[debian_package.id] = debian_package.dependencies

    sorted_dependencies = TopologicalSort(dependency_map).sort()
    sorted_dependencies = map(lambda package_id: debian_packages[package_id].file_path, sorted_dependencies)
    return sorted_dependencies


def main():
    # ------------------
    # Sort the packages using topological sort

    packages_dir_path = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'packages')
    logging.info('sorting packages in "{}" using topological sort ...'.format(packages_dir_path))
    sorted_packages = sort_debian_packages(packages_dir_path)

    # ------------------
    # Install the packages in the sorted order

    for index, package_file_path in enumerate(sorted_packages):
        command = 'dpkg -i {}'.format(package_file_path)
        logging.info('executing "{}" ...'.format(command))
        subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if os.geteuid() != 0:
        logging.error('must be run as root')
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        main()
    except:
        logging.error('failed to install packages', exc_info=True)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Probably this script has become old and needs an update? Here's the message I get: `    metadata = metadata.replace('\n ', '\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: @aderchox - in python3. to fix, you need to add `metadata.decode().replace(...`

Comment: Ah thanks, but to my surprise I found an easier way for apt `sudo apt install ./* && sudo apt --fix-broken install ./*`.

Answer (score 6):

You can try with -R and install options:

```
sudo dpkg -R --install dependencies/
```

**-R** Recursive handle all regular files matching pattern *.deb found at specific directories and all of its subdirectories

Comment: -1, this does not work. same situation as in question

Comment: this solution worked well for installing dir of bunch of .deb files all inter-tangled with deps between them

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a dpkg expert, but its `--force-depends` flag seems to work.

I'd make sure all the dependencies are fulfilled first using `dkpg-deb -I <package.deb>` or better yet, recursively for every `.deb` you have in the current folder:

```
ls -1 -d "$PWD"/* | xargs --max-lines=1 dpkg-deb -I | grep --only-matching --perl-regexp "(?<=Depends: ).*" | sed -z 's/, /\n/g' | sort | uniq -u
```

If all these dependencies are contained in the pwd or already installed on the system, then simply install all `.debs` in the pwd with:

```
dpkg --force-depends -i ./*
```

To read more about the force flag:

```
man dpkg --force-help
```

Comment: `--force-conflicts` was also needed on my end