# Ubuntu 18.04 system broken after uninstalling openssl

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, openssl, rails

I am very new to Ubuntu and to rails. I tried to do a bundle install after installing rails through rvm, but I had an error back with the openssl. I looked online for a solution and I uninstalled the openssl with this command sudo apt-get remove --purge openssl
After that chrome and software center disappeared, I am not able to even install the software center and I have this message back when I try to do so.
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate

How can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that's rough.  You might want to try downloading the package manually (on another computer or via the live disc) from the [Ubuntu packages site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic).  Here's how I'd do it.

1. Figure out if you still have the dependencies by running `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep install | grep -e libc6 -e libssl1.1`.  Here, libc6 and libssl1.1 are the required packages.  Make sure in the output, each of these is present and they are followed by a colon and the architecture of your system (e.g., `libc6:amd64`).  If you are missing these, you will need to get them as well (use this same process, just complete them first).
2. On another computer or a live disc, [download the .deb file from the packages site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/openssl) (make sure you get the one that is for your version of Ubuntu and your processor architecture) and copy it onto the broken system.
3. Navigate to the directory with the .deb file and run `sudo dpkg -i <OPENSSL_PACKAGE>.deb`
4. Update your system to make sure things have been repaired `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`.  You may have to reinstall the software center.

That *should* resolve your issue without you needing to reinstall your system, but I haven't tested it myself.

If you get into a chain of missing dependencies and you don't know the order in which to install the packages, it [looks like there is a script to help with that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708067/install-multiple-deb-files-while-respecting-their-dependencies).